# Jmeter HTTPS proxy configuration

Tags: https, jmeter

I am trying to use jmeter to load test https website. I have installed the client certificates(.pfx) using the keytool in the proxyserver.jks file in jmeter/bin.

I have also configured the jmeter proxy and firefox using jmeter manual (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

Also configured the HTTP request sampler to have the protocol as "https". But while running firefox i get the error "The connection to  was reset  while the page was loading."

I am using the below config
Win XP 32 bit with SP3 
jmeter 2.8
firefox 21.0

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS recording
JMeter proxy server uses a dummy certificate to enable it to accept the SSL connection from the browser. This certificate is not one of the certificates that browsers normally trust, and will not be for the correct host.
As a consequence:

If the browser hasn't already registered a certificate for the domain of your URL, it should display a dialogue asking if you want to accept the certificate or not. For example:

1) The server's name "www.example.com" does not match the certificate's name "JMeter Proxy". Somebody may be trying to eavesdrop on you.

2) The certificate for "JMeter Proxy" is signed by the unknown Certificate Authority "JMeter Proxy". It is not possible to verify that this is a valid certificate.

You will need to accept the certificate in order to allow the JMeter Proxy to intercept the SSL traffic in order to record it. You should only accept the certificate temporarily. Browsers only prompt this dialogue for the certificate of the main url, not for the resources loaded in the page, such as images, css or javascript files hosted on a secured external CDN. If you have such resources (gmail has for example), you'll have to first browse manually to these other domains in order to accept JMeter's certificate for them. Check in jmeter.log for secure domains that you need to register certificate for.

If the browser has already registered a validated certificate for this domain, the browser will detect JMeter as a security breach and will refuse to load the page. If so, you have to remove the trusted certificate from your browser's keystore.

Comment: Thanks,The issue is i already have registered my certificates in the proxyserver.jks file. do i need to make any changes in the jmeter.properties file under #SSL configuration ? Also in the jmeter.properties file, i have uncommented the following
--------------------------------------------------------------------
https.default.protocol=SSLv3
https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1
https.use.cached.ssl.context=true
--------------------------------------------------------------------
in case i have my own certificates, are you saying i have to remove the Apache jmeter proxy certificate

Comment: after i have setup the proxy and i run firefox for recording, i get an error in firefox saying "The connection to <server> was interrupted while the page was loading." instantly.

Comment: go back to default jmeter config and follow instructions precisely, also read before jmeter proxy recording step by step http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: you don't need to add any certificate to jks, it is done by browser , you just need to accept exception