# JMeter: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake" while recording in JMeter

Tags: ssl, proxy, certificate, jmeter, handshake

While recording I can see following error:

```html
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 ... 17 more
```

What is the possible solution to get this sorted out?

Comment: You just asked another question very similar to this. And again, it appears that you are recording https and has issues with certs. Please research similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981632/jmeter-https-proxy-configuration

Comment: Hi Kiril, I have already confirmed security certificate still it takes a while for jmeter to record the actions, manually there is no delay in any action. I have refered this link to accept certificate https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server

Comment: Please refer to this link, similar question asked here and had some good responses which I am trying now.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009083/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failure-when-using-jmeter-with-ss